# Trying to create geometry dash account. Keep getting "invalid email"

Tags: geometry-dash

I was trying to create a geometry dash account. It kept saying "invalid email". How can it be invalid when it's the only email I have?

Comment: It generally needs an email with an @ and a . With 2+ characters after it

Answer (score 6):

<s>I solved it by registering [here](http://www.boomlings.com/database/accounts/register.php).</s>

I found this link by clicking the "help" button in the login dialog and guessing the file name of the registering page.

If you don't trust me, you can get to that page by clicking that button by yourself and changing the file name to "register.php".

UPDATE: I guess they have deleted that page now, and I can't find an alternative to that by searching `register site:boomlings.com`. However, I found this: http://www.boomlings.com/database/accounts/invalidEmail.php

Comment: The link is down now.

Comment: The invalidEmail.php link fixed it for me!

Answer (score 1):

What is the email domain you are trying to use? If the game detects your email is a different domain, (such as @yopmail) it could think its invalid.

Try creating a new gmail account and using that.

Answer (score -1):

It is nothing to do with people's individual email address. It has to be a problem with the game's servers. Sort it out robtop, This problem has been going on for months and months.

Answer (score -2):

Make sure you're spelling everything right. Also, if your email is a gmail account, be sure to put @gmail.com at the end of it; it's a Hotmail account, make sure to put @Hotmail.com, and that applies to whatever website your email account is on.

Comment: This answer does not really make sense